# How to disable Gutenberg editor from Multisite Admin panel?

Tags: multisite, block-editor

I recently Updated WordPress to 5.2.2 and I want to disable Gutenberg editor from network. By this way, I do not need to go into each sites and disable one by one.

I have already installed Disable Gutenberg plugin but this plugin would not show any relevant option to disable through the network level.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically disable Gutenberg network-wide by adding a [must-use plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) containing this code:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false' );
```

### References

- [Must-Use Plugins](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/)
- [`use_block_editor_for_post` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/use_block_editor_for_post/)
- [`__return_false()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_false/)